# Google cloud and Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I am trying to run geth on google cloud.
I finnaly managed to install it, but when running it, it's not syncyng with the blockchain (rynkeby).

```
INFO [10-18|10:24:28] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=1
INFO [10-18|10:24:28] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17
179869184
INFO [10-18|10:24:28] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17
179869184
INFO [10-18|10:24:28] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17
179869184
```

Running geth --fast at beggining did not change anything.

Why is it not syncyng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open TCP and UDP ports 30303

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to open up TCP port 30303 and UDP ports 30303 and 30304.

Also, if you want to connect to it via HTTP/RPC you need to enable that when you start geth and open port 8545.  That's the default, but you can change it.  Or, better yet, connect via an SSH tunnel.

Regardless, for RPC access I suggest you lock down the origin IP to be only from your own and other trusted ones.